# Using boost::bind() across C code, will it work?

Tags: c++, c, boost, boost-bind, libev

Can I use `boost::bind(mycallback, this, _1, _2)` across C code?

**Update**

The short answer is **no**, boost bind does not return a function pointer, which can be called in C code, but a *functor* (C++ object with overloaded `()` operator) see answer below.

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you want to do. Until then I'd say the answer is "no".

Comment: Please at the **very least** give us the declaration of `invoke_callback`!

Comment: `void invoke_callback(void* funcptr)` but I figured it out already, boost is not the best way to go in my case (using a C library), thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do what you want to do is to create a C callback that then calls the boost::function, which is stored in some sort of user memory with new.

Example:

```
void callFunction(void* data)
{

   boost::function<void(void)> *func = (boost::function<void(void)>* ) (data);
   (*func)();
   delete(func);
}
```

Then you simply pass this callback and set the user data(however it is specified in libev) to be a copy of your function allocated with new.

This is how you specify user data with libev:
http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#ASSOCIATING_CUSTOM_DATA_WITH_A_WATCH

Comment: This would work if libev had a good place to store per descriptor user-data.

Comment: @unixman83 You can store user data for libev quite easily. I added the link from the docs to my answer. You can either stuff it in the void*data member that is in each watcher or subclass the watcher and add a full boost::function member.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I did not see that. I did see the per-loop which is Not what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

No.  `boost::bind` returns a *Functor* not a function pointer.  The returned object is a C++ object which has an overloaded `operator()` which allows it to behave *like* a function pointer in C++ code.  But it is not a function pointer which can be passed into C code.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to use whatever `boost::bind` returns as a callback function for a C library?

If that's the case, then no, it won't work. It won't even build, as `boost::bind` does not return a function pointer.