# pthread member function of a class with arguments

Tags: c++, pthreads, bind, functor

I was successful at attaching a thread to class member using the code on the bottom of this page: http://www.tuxtips.org/?p=5.

I can't figure out how to expand the code to encapsulate a method such as `void* atom(void *inst`) where `*inst` is a structure that contains various thread parameters. Specifically neither Netbeans nor I understand where the `example::*f` is defined and how it can be valid in the `thread_maker` scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better solution for using things such as pthread(which take c callbacks) is to create a wrapper function so that you can use much easier to manipulate boost::functions instead. This is  similar to [Using boost::bind() across C code, will it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282599/using-boostbind-across-c-code-will-it-work/8282659#8282659).

Then you could solve your problem simply with boost::bind

```
class myClass
{
    void atom(myStruct *data); // void return type to keep it similar to other code
    // You could change it to a void* return type, but then you would need to change the boost::function declarations
};

boost::function<void(void)> function = boost::bind(&myClass::atom,&myClassInstance,&myStructInstance); //bind your function
boost::function<void(void)>* functionCopy = new boost::function<void(void)> (function); //create a copy on the heap

pthread_t id;
pthread_create(&id,NULL,&functionWrapper,functionCopy);
```

The wrapper function would look like this.

```
void functionWrapper(void* data)
{

   boost::function<void(void)> *func = (boost::function<void(void)>* ) (data);
   (*func)();
   delete(func);
}
```

While this method may be more work than manually passing in data, it is much more extendable, making it easy to bind anything and pass it to start your thread.

**EDIT**

One last note: myClassInstance and myStructInstance should be on the heap. If they are on the stack they could get deleted before your thread starts.

Comment: I don't know enough about function pointers to understand how to pass parameters through functionCopy? Can you possible add the lines where you explicitly pass a structure into functionCopy?

Comment: @Misha If you look at the line above the creation of function copy, it is boost::bind which turns the member function, the structure , and the data into a single boost::function. The basic idea of boost::bind is that it turns something like `void blah(int a)` into `void blah()`. Member functions are handled as if it was a regular free function with the first parameter being a pointer to the object it is a member of. e.g. `myClass::atom(myStruct *data)` = `anonFunc(myClass* this, myStruct *data)`

Comment: @Misha One other thing to note, using boost::functions is very different from function pointers. Function pointers cannot hold any state(only space for the address of the function). Boost::functions can hold tons of state.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this one up, this seems much easier than what was being done on the other site!